# Remove CAGradientLayer with alpha animation on UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, cagradientlayer

I have a bottom fade-out gradient layer on `UITextView`. I'm deleting this fade-out when user reaches the bottom of `UIScrollView`. However, when user started to scroll to top, I set it again.

**My Problem** is that I want to delete this `CAGradientLayer` with alpha animation not just directly remove it.

Now I'm removing and setting it with (without animation):

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    updateGradientFrame()
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height) {
           self.myTextView.layer.mask = nil
    }else{
        myTextView.layer.mask = gradient
    }}
```

What I tried and doesn't work:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
   self.myTextView.layer.mask = nil
}
```

Another try (this adds animation to whole `UITextView` not just the layer):

```
let flash = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
flash.fromValue = 1.0
flash.toValue = 0.0
flash.duration = 3.0 // 1 second
flash.autoreverses = false // Back

gradient.add(flash, forKey: "flashAnimation")
```

What I found on community (Not directly refers to this question):

[Animating a CALayer's mask size change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910770/animating-a-calayers-mask-size-change)

[Animate CALayer mask change with fade effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27638033/animate-calayer-mask-change-with-fade-effect)

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this ?

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        yourLayer.opacity = 0
    }, completion: {
        yourLayer.removeFromSuperLayer()
    })
```

Here you animate the opacity with 1 as duration, then when it completes you just remove it from its super layer.